# Change image SRC for image that reside in a cloned DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a predefined `DIV` as below:

```
<div id="innerDropzone" style="position: absolute; top: 20px; left: 30px; width: 200px; height: 200px">
    <img id="img" src="watever"/>
</div>
```

Base on some event being fired, I will clone the above `DIV` as below:

```
var newDiv = $('#innerDropzone').clone();
                                    //newDiv.attr('id', 'pin' + $("#clicks").children('.pin').length);
$(newDiv).css('display', 'block');
//$(newDiv).attr('');

$('#dropzone').append(newDiv);
$(newDiv).draggable();
```

I'm wondering how to change the img SRC for this `newDiv`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.find()`:

```
$(newDiv).find("img").attr("src",a);
```

or `.children()` (`.children()` only travels a single level down the DOM tree. So it will be faster.):

```
$(newDiv).children("img").attr("src",a);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) and [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

```
$(newDiv).find("img").attr("src",a);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/Kcaaj/)

```
var newDiv = $('#innerDropzone').clone();

$(newDiv).css('display', 'block').find('img').attr('src','abc.png');
```